# Spark (Scala) modify the contents of a Dataset Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to have a Dataset, where the first column contains single words and the second column contains the filenames of the files where these words appear.
My current code looks something like this:

```
val path = "path/to/folder/with/files"
val tokens = spark.read.textFile(path).
    .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    .withColumn("filename", input_file_name)

tokens.show()
```

However this returns something like

```
|word1     |whole/path/to/some/file     |
|word2     |whole/path/to/some/file     |
|word1     |whole/path/to/some/otherfile|
```

(I don't need the whole path, just the last bit). My idea to fix this, was to use the map function

```
val tokensNoPath =  tokens.
    map(r => (r(0), r(1).asInstanceOf[String].split("/").lastOption))
```

So basically, just going to every tow, grabbing the second entry and deleting everything before the last slash.

However since I'm very new to Spark and Scala I can't figure out how to get the syntax for this right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs:
[substring_index](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#substring_index) "substring_index(str, delim, count) Returns the substring from str before count occurrences of the delimiter delim... If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned."

```
.withColumn("filename", substring_index(input_file_name, "/", -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by slash and get the last element:

```
val tokens2 = tokens.withColumn("filename", element_at(split(col("filename"), "/"), -1))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get it to work.
Getting a compiler error: could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,String,VR]